# How to get selected radio input array in controller on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm working on Laravel with radio input group and trying to pass to controller. Below is my blade.

```
    @foreach ($testtransactions as $key => $testtransaction)
         <div class="form-check">
           <input type="radio" name="choice{{$key}}" id="1" value="1" class="form-check-input">
         </div>
         <div class="form-check">
           <input type="radio" name="choice{{$key}}" id="2" value="2" class="form-check-input">
         </div>
         <div class="form-check">
           <input type="radio" name="choice{{$key}}" id="3" value="3" class="form-check-input">
         </div>
         <div class="form-check">
           <input type="radio" name="choice{{$key}}" id="4" value="4" class="form-check-input">
         </div>
    @endforeach
```

I try to get value in controller as below code but not success.

```
public function TestSave(Request $request){
    $choices = $request->choice;
    return $choices;
}
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple HTML. Assuming `$key` is unique you need to make the radio button name `choice[{{$key}}]`.

In the backend/controller you access it as `$request->choice` just keep in mind that it will be an array.

Comment: Dear Pablo, Seem work but it's only value. like [
"1",
"4"
]. Then, how can I get id pair. Thank you very much.

Comment: @joenpcnpcsolution Paired to what? if $key is 0 than 1 than it should result in [0 => '1', 1 => '4'] which is identical to `[ "1", "4" ]`. Makes sense?

Comment: Dear Pablo, Thanks. But if I have 3 groups but the second not selected. Then the result is the same [ "1", "4" ]. That's wrong.

Comment: Dear Dear Pablo, work great with a bit changed     public function TestSave(Request $request){
        $choices = $request->choice;
        foreach ($choices as $key => $choice) {
            echo "id: " . $key . " "  . $choice;
        }
        return ;
    }

Comment: I glad you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Chang radios name from `choice{{$key}}` to `choice[]`

Comment: Dear MohamedSabil83, Thanks for advice. Anyway, Could you pls get more details?. It's not single group of raio button, so can not use only adding [] to the name. The number of group are generated by $testtransactions count.

Comment: Can you dump sample data from both of $key and $testtransaction?

Comment: Dear MohamedSabil83, Actually that's the problem. I do not know how to loop thru the name array and its' key.

Comment: Dump $testtransactions and put it here or screenshot from dumping result

Answer (score 0):

friends, radio invoked

```
@foreach ($testtransactions as $key => $testtransaction)
         <div class="form-check">
           <input type="radio" name="choice[]" id="1" value="1" class="form-check-input" {{ $testtransaction->active) ? 'checked' : ''}} >
         </div>
         <div class="form-check">
           <input type="radio" name="choice[]" id="2" value="2" class="form-check-input" {{ $testtransaction->active) ? 'checked' : ''}} >
         </div>
         <div class="form-check">
           <input type="radio" name="choice[]" id="3" value="3" class="form-check-input" {{ $testtransaction->active) ? 'checked' : ''}} >
         </div>
         <div class="form-check">
           <input type="radio" name="choice[]" id="4" value="4" class="form-check-input" {{ $testtransaction->active) ? 'checked' : ''}} >
         </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Dear Danny Escalante, Appreciated much for helping on blade. Kindly advice how to handle in controller. Btw, to select option will be action by user not read form variable. Thank you very much.